# How to break an infinite condition by setting a timeout in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm executing programs in a batch file. I want to break if the batch script runs more than some time(say 10 sec). Because it might become an infinite loop.

```
cls
::set timeout here
program.exe
::after timeout continue from here
```

Is there any suggestion to do this in a windows batch file? Plus, is it possible to define the line of endless loop in a batch script?

Comment: What are you trying to monitor, the time the batch file runs, or the time that the `program.exe` runs?  If it exceeds say *10 seconds*, then what does `break` mean -- do you want to terminate the batch file, or terminate `program.exe`?  And what do you mean by `the line of endless loop`?

Comment: I meant the time that the `program.exe` runs. Terminate the program.exe and run from the next line in the batch file. `The line of endless loop` implied the place where infinite condition happened in the program.

Comment: This question might be ridiculus for only one `program.exe` but if there are more than one `program.exe` running in a for loop in batch file, then it will be useful. Because some `program.exe` might have infinite loops some not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run a program from a batch file, you either run it and wait for it to terminate before executing the next command in the batch file, or you launch the program and executing immediately continues in the batch file.  There is no way to measure how long a program runs.  However, you can use certain techniques to see if a program is running and terminate it.  You can also insert delays.  So you can do what you are asking (more or less):

```
cls
start program.exe
ping -n 10 -w 1000 127.0.0.1 > nul 2>&1
tasklist | find /i "program.exe"
if %errorlevel%==0 taskkill /im program.exe
```

This starts the program and immediately starts to execute the next line of code, the `ping`.  The `ping` causes a 10 second delay.  The `tasklist` command pipes the list to `find`, which looks for the program.  If it is found in the list, then it is still running and `errorlevel` is set to `0`, which means the next line terminates the program.

This isn't fool proof however, because if `program.exe` is a common program name, then `tasklist` and `taskkill` will terminate all processes with the same program name (not just the instance you started).

Answer (score 1):

How about that?

```
start calc.exe
ping -n 10 localhost >nul
taskkill /F /IM calc.exe
```